# Как настроить аутентификацию WooCommerce API?

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce, rest

Добрый день, не могу понять как использовать API WooCommerce, пишу в адресной строке 
`/wp-json/wc/v1/orders`, выводит ошибку 401 - что означает не пройдена аутентификация.

Суть вопроса - как пройти аутентификацию? Какие параметры нужно включить в запрос?
Пробовал сделать так:

```
/wp-json/wc/v1/orders?consumer_key=123&consumer_secret=abc
```

(где вместо 123 и abc соответствующие созданные ключи) все равно не получилось.

Использую протокол https.
Инструкцию и доки тут - woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/

Помогите разобраться!

Answer (score 1):

1. Делаешь все по инструкции для [получения ключей](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/)
2. Скачай этот [репозиторий](https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library)
3. В папке example найди файл example.php и в 15 строке замени параметры на свои
4. В ЭТОМ ЖЕ ФАЛЕ, ниже, прописаны доступные функции которыми можно пользоваться!!!!(просто снимай коммент и тестируй)